# How to hide and display input fields on basis on checkbox true false in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Thee are three vales in array `socialMediaDetail[]`,
I have to show and hide below input fields on basis of checkbox , if checkbox is true then show else hide .And this check box true and false I have to set on array response . `if name ==="twitter" ?true:false`; and I have to show twitter link in below twitter input fields .
but all values in array in this array 3 name and 3 links . How can put the conditions .Please help please

How can I achieve below  ,outside function value I have to access in state

```
class UpdateNotificationpreference extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const{navigation}=this.props;
    const{contactDetails,socialMediaDetails}= navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0];
    const{socialMediaDetail}=socialMediaDetails;
    socialMediaDetail.map((data, index) => {
      const twitter= data.name==="twitter";
    });
    this.state = {
      title: 'Update Notification Preference',
      mobile: navigation.state.params.serviceNumber,
      icon: 'sim',
      isChecked: false,
      email: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].contactDetails.emailId,
      smsNum: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].contactDetails.mobileNo,
      phoneNum: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].contactDetails.mobileNo,
      isContactByEmail: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].contactDetails.isContactByEmail==="Y"?true : false,
      isContactByPost:navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].contactDetails.isContactByPost==="Y"?true : false,
      isContactBySms: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].contactDetails.isContactBySms==="Y"?true : false,
      facebook: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail[1].name==="facebook"?true : false,
      isTwitter:this.twitter==="twitter"?true:false,
```

Below is array value:

```
socialMediaDetails:
  socialMediaDetail: Array(2)
    0:
      link: "HARIRAM@twitter.com"
      name: "twitter"
      __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
      __proto__: Object
    1:
      link: "VarnaHERO@facebook.com"
      name: "facebook"
      __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
      __proto__: Object
    2:
      link: "linkedIn@linkedin.com"
      name: "linkedIn"
      __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
```

Here is the code:

```js
  <RegularText style={{ fontWeight: 'normal' }} text={`SOCIAL MEDIA`} textColor="dimgrey"/>
</View> 
<View style={{borderBottomColor: 'dimgrey',borderBottomWidth: 0.3, color:'dimgrey'}} />

<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',paddingLeft:15,marginTop:8,marginBottom:15 }}>
  <View style={{flexDirection:'column', marginBottom:15,marginTop:8}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <View >
      <CheckBox color="#00678f" checked={true}/>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>Facebook</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <CheckBox color="#00678f"
         checked={true}
          onPress={() =>this.handleChangeEmail()}/>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>Whatsapp</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <CheckBox color="#00678f" 
        checked={true}
         onPress={() =>this.handleChangeSMS()}/>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>Twitter</Text>
      </View>

    </View>
  </View>
<View style={{marginBottom:15,paddingLeft:15}}>
  <View>
    <View style={{
      flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor:'#fff',marginBottom:8}}>
      <IconSmall icon="facebook" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={{ color: '#808080',paddingRight: 5 }}/>
      <SmallText textColor="grey" text={`Facebook`}/>
    </View>
    <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1, marginLeft:0}}>
      <Input
        value={this.state.email}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})}
      />
    </Item>
  </View>
  <View style={{marginTop:15}}>
    <View style={{
      flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor:'#fff',marginBottom:8}}>
    <IconSmall icon="whatsapp" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={{ color: '#808080',paddingRight: 5 }}/>
    <SmallText textColor="grey" text={`Whatsapp`}/>
    </View>
    <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1, marginLeft:0}}>
      <Input
        value={this.state.smsNum}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({smsNum:text})}
      />
    </Item>
  </View>
  {this.state.twitter=== true  &&
    <View style={{marginTop:15}}>
      <View style={{
          flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
        <IconSmall icon="twitter" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={{ color: '#808080',paddingRight: 5 }}/>
        <SmallText textColor="grey" text={`Twitter`}/>
      </View>
      <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1, marginLeft:0}}>
        <Input
          value={this.state.faxNum}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({faxNum:text})}
        />
      </Item>
    </View>}
</View>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, the `checked` property of the `Checkbox` should be from a state field.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    checked: true
  }
}
```

[....]

```
<CheckBox 
    color="#00678f"
    checked={this.state.checked}
    onPress={() =>{
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
        this.handleChangeEmail()}}
/>
```

Then you have to create a conditional view (that appears based on a condition), you can create a function that return this view:

```
getMyInputField(){
    if(this.state.checked === false){
        return null; //nothing to show
    }
    return(
        <YourInputView/>
    )
}
```

[...]

And Whenever you need to show that conditional view:

```
{this.getMyInputField()}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , but main problem is there are three value in name ,facebook,twitter and whatsapp , how do i set condition for all 3 inputs , like if name=== face then facebook  fields should display

Comment: https://xd.adobe.com/view/ff27bea6-4608-4033-64a5-2408d8c4c652-8916/screen/49d230d7-9403-4048-b807-f88d1fafe825/Android-Mobile-146?fullscreen

Comment: @AbhigyanGaurav same concept, you need then three booleans on the state (facebookChecked, twitterChecked and whatsappChecked for example) and three functions that each one return the field you need. then use all those three functions.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this how can i do

Comment: I have just updated my question , one point added ,please see