# How to take particular key value from multiple value array in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In socialMediaDetail array there are multiple values , now I have to just take facebook or twitter in separate variable. How would I do that . I tried below code but in that full value is coming name and link both . Please help

```
socialMediaDetails:
        socialMediaDetail: Array(2)
        0:
        link: "HARIRAM@twitter.com"
        name: "twitter"
        __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
        __proto__: Object
        1:
        link: "VarnaHERO@facebook.com"
        name: "facebook"
        __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
        __proto__: Object
        2:
        link: "linkedIn@linkedin.com"
        name: "linkedIn"
        __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"

    const socialMediaData=socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail;

        const Steplabels = socialMediaData.filter((item) => {
          return item.name === "twitter"
        });

        console.log("twittr",Steplabels);  

    // below value is coming 
    0:
    link: "HARIRAM@twitter.com"
    name: "twitter"
    __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: what is the expected result? presumably not just `const Steplabels = "twitter"`...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309834/how-to-hide-and-display-input-fields-on-basis-on-checkbox-true-false-in-react-na/57310444?noredirect=1#comment101113315_57310444

Comment: I have to take all three name and later I have to put conditions .like name==='twitter?true:false; same for const ABC =facebook name==='facebook?true:false

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Could you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Or at the very least please ask a question - a full sentence with a question mark, without "do that"...

Comment: const result = socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail.map(x => x.name).find(x => x === 'twitter');

Comment: solved sir ,thanks for your help

Comment: but that is almost the same as `const result = 'twitter'` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes sir..Thanks for your time..thanks a lot :)